# use lodash or for loop for different reasons?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am curious if it is possible to replace this for loop with lodash functions? and how would you implement it? why would you (or wouldn't you) replace the for loop with lodash function(s) for performance reasons or readability?

```
  for (var i = 0; (i + 3) < username.length + 1; i++) {
    if (_.includes(password, username.substring(i, i + 3))) {
      warning = "Passwords cannot contain 3 or more " +
        "consecutive characters from user name";
      alerting.addDanger(warning);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: There is rarely a project's aim of "use lodash as much as possible" anywhere in the world.

Comment: Lodash is a utility library, so you will mostly use it to do the things you don't want to do yourself. It's not that your for loop is faster or slower, but instead of repeating it multiple time in your code, with the risk of introducing errors, you could instead just use lodash that uses a tested method.

Comment: Also, since you are trying to implement password rules, [here is a good read from a founder of Stackoverflow](https://blog.codinghorror.com/password-rules-are-bullshit/)

Comment: Another general advantage of Lodash is that it ensures cross browser compatibility, so you don't have to deal with [polyfills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill) for functions that aren't supported by some browsers.